# In jackson how do i exclude few fields in runtime if their value is null or not set?

Tags: json, jackson

I want to do the run time exclusion in Jackson.

In the below example which has three variables

```
public class Field {

//------------------------- private variables ----------------------------
private A header;
private B values;
private C argvalues;

//------------------------- constructors ----------------------------------

public Field(A header, B values) {      
    this.header = header;
    this.values = values;
}
public Field(A header, C values) {      
    this.header = header;
    this.argvalues = values;
}

public Field() {

}
//--------------------- getter-setter -------------------------------------
public A getHeader() {
    return header;
}

public void setHeader(A header) {
    this.header = header;
}

public B getValues() {
    return values;
}

public void setValues(B values) {
    this.values = values;
}
public C getArgvalues() {
    return argvalues;
}

public void setArgvalues(C argvalues) {
    this.argvalues = argvalues;
}


    }
```

Suppose if any of the variables are not set at runtime , how do i exclude them from the json. Please help .

<--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@---->

when we are using @ JsonProperty in the below example

```
public String getType() {

    return type;

}

@ JsonProperty("Json")

public void setType(String type) {

    this.type = type;

}


public List<TwoDArrayItem> getItems() {

    return items;

}


@ JsonProperty("Json")

public void setItems(List<TwoDArrayItem> items) {

    this.items = items;

}
```

At any point of time i will be setting only one setter method 
but the JsonProperty name should be same for both . when i am compiling this i am getting error. How to  set the same name for both .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To always exclude null values for the given object, you can annotate it with:

```
@JsonSerialize(include=Inclusion.NON_NULL) // Jackson 1.9 or lower
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)             // Jackson 2 or higher
public class Field {
    // ...
}
```

As opposed to excluding null values for the entire object, you can exclude them for specific fields:

```
public class Field {
    private A header;
    private B values;

    @JsonSerialize(include=Inclusion.NON_NULL) // Jackson 1.9 or lower
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)             // Jackson 2 or higher
    private C argvalues;

    // ...
}
```

To dynamically exclude null values for a given session, create an object mapper and configure it too exclude nulls.

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Comment: what if i want to exclude only few particular variables if their value is null ?

Comment: You want to serialize some nulls and exclude others? Is that what you mean?

Comment: The annotations I mentioned can be applied to specific fields (as opposed to the entire object). See edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you r answer. I have one more  doubt. Please see the bottom of first post.

Comment: @Naveen - thats a totally separate question, and should be posted as such.